# Authentication in a webpart return a Null Exception

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to make a authentication WebPart. For this, i used tghios tutorial:
http://blogs.codes-sources.com/anouvel/archive/2010/09/18/sharepoint-2010-d-velopper-une-web-part-d-authentification-pour-une-page-d-accueil.aspx

But this line doesn't work and return me a Null:
    SPIisSettings settings = webApp.IisSettings[SPContext.Current.Site.Zone];

I don't understand why?

May be somebody Can Help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try using ULS viewer and find any related errors

Comment: also can you check if your getting anything for "SPContext.Current.Site.Zone" or if its null

Answer (score 0):

try this instead, might help

```
 SPIisSettings iisSettings = this.webApp.IisSettings[this.zone];
```

OR use this one

```
SPUrlZone.Default
```

instead of "this.zone"

Comment: I've got an erreor message: My Webpart doesn't contain a defintion for Zone. I miss something?

Comment: Zone is just part of page where you add your webpart to, so don't think that is the problem

Comment: Sorry I don't have a zone property on my object this.

Comment: sorry I was confused so ignore my 1st comment, I guess you need to create a new zone maybe, check this link out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx